# Optimizing spark sql Cartesian join

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to perform a Cartesian join on two data sets of 3M and 1M each. That means each row in a 3M data set should be joined to each row in 1M data set. After that I have to perform multiple other joins on the Cartesian product. It takes around 9 days to run the code using PySpark. Is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: Hi! Could you post the coe that you use to perform the Cartesian join? That way we can see what can be optimized.

Comment: Not sure Cartesian product can, needs to be optimized.

Comment: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/6747/how-do-i-get-a-cartesian-product-of-a-huge-dataset.html

Comment: @Titulum The code that I have written before the Cartesian join is pretty big which eventuallly creates 2 tables which in turn are being joined. So eventually the query becomes: "select a.v1,a.v1 from tableA a cross join tableB b"

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same scenario earlier but couldn't do join optimisation.so instead I changed my spark executor  configurations as per the third options mentioned in below link
https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html
Please check this out

Comment: I have tried optimizing the configurations but still it's not executing .